# BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000030 (Ubuntu 14.04, kernel: 4.4.0-31)

Tags: 14.04, kernel, iptables

I get the following "log" output using "crash"

```
[558679.340881] ip_tables: error: `ERROR'
[558679.344717] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000030
[558679.344779] IP: [<ffffffffc02c6bb9>] ipt_do_table+0x2a9/0x6d0 [ip_tables]
[558679.344822] PGD 1fc9318067 PUD 1fed08c067 PMD 0 
[558679.344862] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[558679.344883] Modules linked in: ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack xt_multiport iptable_filter xt_tcpudp xt_CT nf_conntrack iptable_raw ip_tables x_tables bridge stp llc xfrm_user xfrm_algo aufs intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul dm_multipath aesni_intel aes_x86_64 ipmi_devintf lrw ipmi_ssif gf128mul glue_helper sb_edac ablk_helper joydev input_leds cryptd edac_core lpc_ich shpchp 8250_fintek mac_hid acpi_power_meter ipmi_si ipmi_msghandler iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid0 multipath linear raid1 ast ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea ixgbe sysfillrect igb sysimgblt vxlan fb_sys_fops ip6_udp_tunnel
[558679.345361]  hid_generic mxm_wmi dca udp_tunnel usbhid ptp drm hid ahci pps_core i2c_algo_bit libahci mdio fjes wmi
[558679.345414] CPU: 11 PID: 21879 Comm: scalerd.bin Not tainted 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[558679.345441] Hardware name: Quanta Computer Inc. X-100.Scaler.01/S2PC-MB(Dual 1G LOM), BIOS S2P_3B04.HGT04 04/12/2017
[558679.345473] task: ffff881fcad13700 ti: ffff881fcda98000 task.ti: ffff881fcda98000
[558679.345496] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc02c6bb9>]  [<ffffffffc02c6bb9>] ipt_do_table+0x2a9/0x6d0 [ip_tables]
[558679.345528] RSP: 0018:ffff881fcda9b950  EFLAGS: 00010246
[558679.345546] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff883fef727f30 RCX: 0000000000000000
[558679.345575] RDX: 0000000000000034 RSI: 0000000000000006 RDI: 0000000000000000
[558679.345603] RBP: ffff881fcda9ba80 R08: 000000005ae4582f R09: 00000000ffff4cec
[558679.345625] R10: ffff883fef727f30 R11: ffff883fed060000 R12: ffff883f105284fc
[558679.345652] R13: ffff883fef727fa0 R14: ffffffffc02ca718 R15: ffff883fef152d00
[558679.345676] FS:  00007f950998e700(0000) GS:ffff883fff040000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[558679.345703] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[558679.345721] CR2: 0000000000000030 CR3: 0000001fdfe84000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
[558679.345744] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[558679.345766] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[558679.345787] Stack:
[558679.345799]  ffffffff81d38580 ffff881fecc02d00 ffff881fed3e0000 0000000000000000
[558679.345833]  00ff881fed3e0000 ffff881fed3e0090 ffff883fee6bbe00 ffff881fecc02d00
[558679.345873]  ffff883fde087a00 ffff881fed3e0000 ffff883fee6bbeac ffff881fcda9b9f0
[558679.345918] Call Trace:
[558679.345936]  [<ffffffff8171857f>] ? sch_direct_xmit+0x6f/0x1f0
[558679.345963]  [<ffffffffc02d10b4>] iptable_raw_hook+0x24/0x53 [iptable_raw]
[558679.345994]  [<ffffffff817280ad>] nf_iterate+0x5d/0x70
[558679.346015]  [<ffffffff81728126>] nf_hook_slow+0x66/0xc0
[558679.346045]  [<ffffffff81733ee4>] __ip_local_out+0xd4/0xe0
[558679.346063]  [<ffffffff817321c0>] ? neigh_key_eq32+0x20/0x20
[558679.346088]  [<ffffffff81733f0c>] ip_local_out+0x1c/0x40
[558679.346121]  [<ffffffff8173425e>] ip_queue_xmit+0x15e/0x390
[558679.346157]  [<ffffffff8174b97b>] tcp_transmit_skb+0x4bb/0x8b0
[558679.346193]  [<ffffffff8174d8bf>] tcp_send_ack+0x10f/0x160
[558679.346228]  [<ffffffff8173bc06>] tcp_cleanup_rbuf+0x76/0x120
[558679.346263]  [<ffffffff8173d6b6>] tcp_recvmsg+0x6a6/0xbc0
[558679.346299]  [<ffffffff8137c2b8>] ? aa_sk_perm+0x78/0x230
[558679.347586]  [<ffffffff81769aaf>] inet_recvmsg+0x6f/0x80
[558679.348910]  [<ffffffff816d685b>] sock_recvmsg+0x3b/0x50
[558679.350248]  [<ffffffff816d777b>] ___sys_recvmsg+0xdb/0x1f0
[558679.351449]  [<ffffffff810a74ef>] ? wake_up_q+0x4f/0x80
[558679.352631]  [<ffffffff810f8d01>] ? futex_wake+0x81/0x150
[558679.353772]  [<ffffffff810fb304>] ? do_futex+0xf4/0x520
[558679.354769]  [<ffffffff816d8212>] __sys_recvmsg+0x42/0x80
[558679.355688]  [<ffffffff816d8262>] SyS_recvmsg+0x12/0x20
[558679.356538]  [<ffffffff817f6f36>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
[558679.357533] Code: d4 3f 41 8b 97 80 00 00 00 48 83 00 01 48 01 50 08 44 0f b7 53 58 49 01 da 41 f6 87 91 00 00 00 01 0f 85 df 01 00 00 49 8b 42 08 <48> 83 78 30 00 0f 84 af 00 00 00 48 89 45 a0 49 8d 42 20 48 8d 
[558679.359673] RIP  [<ffffffffc02c6bb9>] ipt_do_table+0x2a9/0x6d0 [ip_tables]
[558679.360589]  RSP <ffff881fcda9b950>
[558679.361609] CR2: 0000000000000030
```

The "bt -f" output is as follows:

```
crash> bt -f
PID: 21879  TASK: ffff881fcad13700  CPU: 11  COMMAND: "scalerd.bin"
 #0 [ffff881fcda9b630] machine_kexec at ffffffff810598bc
    ffff881fcda9b638: 0000fbff22200800 ffff880000000000 
    ffff881fcda9b648: 0000000015003000 ffff880015003000 
    ffff881fcda9b658: 0000000015002000 0000000000000046 
    ffff881fcda9b668: ffff881fcda9b8a8 ffff881fcda9b690 
    ffff881fcda9b678: 0000000000000046 ffff881fcda9b748 
    ffff881fcda9b688: ffffffff81105c83 
 #1 [ffff881fcda9b688] crash_kexec at ffffffff81105c83
    ffff881fcda9b690: ffff883fef152d00 ffffffffc02ca718 
    ffff881fcda9b6a0: ffff883fef727fa0 ffff883f105284fc 
    ffff881fcda9b6b0: ffff881fcda9ba80 ffff883fef727f30 
    ffff881fcda9b6c0: ffff883fed060000 ffff883fef727f30 
    ffff881fcda9b6d0: 00000000ffff4cec 000000005ae4582f 
    ffff881fcda9b6e0: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9b6f0: 0000000000000034 0000000000000006 
    ffff881fcda9b700: 0000000000000000 ffffffffffffffff 
    ffff881fcda9b710: ffffffffc02c6bb9 0000000000000010 
    ffff881fcda9b720: 0000000000010246 ffff881fcda9b950 
    ffff881fcda9b730: 0000000000000018 0000000000000009 
    ffff881fcda9b740: ffff881fcda9b8a8 ffff881fcda9b770 
    ffff881fcda9b750: ffffffff81030b09 
 #2 [ffff881fcda9b750] oops_end at ffffffff81030b09
    ffff881fcda9b758: ffff881fcda9b8a8 0000000000000009 
    ffff881fcda9b768: 0000000000000000 ffff881fcda9b7c8 
    ffff881fcda9b778: ffffffff8106707d 
 #3 [ffff881fcda9b778] no_context at ffffffff8106707d
    ffff881fcda9b780: ffffea007fbcf100 ffff881fcda9b850 
    ffff881fcda9b790: ffffffff00030001 ffff881fcda9b7a8 
    ffff881fcda9b7a0: 0000000000000000 ffff881fcda9b8a8 
    ffff881fcda9b7b0: 0000000000000030 ffff881fcad13700 
    ffff881fcda9b7c0: 0000000000030001 ffff881fcda9b810 
    ffff881fcda9b7d0: ffffffff810673f9 
 #4 [ffff881fcda9b7d0] __bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff810673f9
    ffff881fcda9b7d8: ffff881fe40a1f90 ffff881fdc694c00 
    ffff881fcda9b7e8: ffff88140d034380 0000000000000030 
    ffff881fcda9b7f8: 0000000000000000 ffff881fcda9b8a8 
    ffff881fcda9b808: ffff881fcad13700 ffff881fcda9b820 
    ffff881fcda9b818: ffffffff81067513 
 #5 [ffff881fcda9b818] bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff81067513
    ffff881fcda9b820: ffff881fcda9b878 ffffffff81067b00 
 #6 [ffff881fcda9b828] __do_page_fault at ffffffff81067b00
    ffff881fcda9b830: ffff881fed10a0e8 00000000000000b3 
    ffff881fcda9b840: ffff88140d0343e8 ffffffffc028ba0f 
    ffff881fcda9b850: 0000000000000000 ffff881fcda9b8a8 
    ffff881fcda9b860: ffff883fef727fa0 ffffffffc02ca718 
    ffff881fcda9b870: ffff883fef152d00 ffff881fcda9b898 
    ffff881fcda9b880: ffffffff81067ec2 
 #7 [ffff881fcda9b880] do_page_fault at ffffffff81067ec2
    ffff881fcda9b888: 0000000000000001 ffff883f105284fc 
    ffff881fcda9b898: ffff881fcda9ba80 ffffffff817f90b8 
 #8 [ffff881fcda9b8a0] page_fault at ffffffff817f90b8
    [exception RIP: ipt_do_table+681]
    RIP: ffffffffc02c6bb9  RSP: ffff881fcda9b950  RFLAGS: 00010246
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: ffff883fef727f30  RCX: 0000000000000000
    RDX: 0000000000000034  RSI: 0000000000000006  RDI: 0000000000000000
    RBP: ffff881fcda9ba80   R8: 000000005ae4582f   R9: 00000000ffff4cec
    R10: ffff883fef727f30  R11: ffff883fed060000  R12: ffff883f105284fc
    R13: ffff883fef727fa0  R14: ffffffffc02ca718  R15: ffff883fef152d00
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
    ffff881fcda9b8a8: ffff883fef152d00 ffffffffc02ca718 
    ffff881fcda9b8b8: ffff883fef727fa0 ffff883f105284fc 
    ffff881fcda9b8c8: ffff881fcda9ba80 ffff883fef727f30 
    ffff881fcda9b8d8: ffff883fed060000 ffff883fef727f30 
    ffff881fcda9b8e8: 00000000ffff4cec 000000005ae4582f 
    ffff881fcda9b8f8: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9b908: 0000000000000034 0000000000000006 
    ffff881fcda9b918: 0000000000000000 ffffffffffffffff 
    ffff881fcda9b928: ffffffffc02c6bb9 0000000000000010 
    ffff881fcda9b938: 0000000000010246 ffff881fcda9b950 
    ffff881fcda9b948: 0000000000000018 ffffffff81d38580 
    ffff881fcda9b958: ffff881fecc02d00 ffff881fed3e0000 
    ffff881fcda9b968: 0000000000000000 00ff881fed3e0000 
    ffff881fcda9b978: ffff881fed3e0090 ffff883fee6bbe00 
    ffff881fcda9b988: ffff881fecc02d00 ffff883fde087a00 
    ffff881fcda9b998: ffff881fed3e0000 ffff883fee6bbeac 
    ffff881fcda9b9a8: ffff881fcda9b9f0 ffffffff8171857f 
    ffff881fcda9b9b8: 0000001eef9caaf0 00000000cda9b9f0 
    ffff881fcda9b9c8: ffff883fee6bbe00 ffff883feee4cd50 
    ffff881fcda9b9d8: 0000000000000003 ffff883fef72600c 
    ffff881fcda9b9e8: ffff881fcda9bb00 ffff883fef2adfe0 
    ffff881fcda9b9f8: ffff883fef726040 ffff883fef726000 
    ffff881fcda9ba08: 0000000100000000 ffffffff00000003 
    ffff881fcda9ba18: ffff883fed060000 ffffffffc032b170 
    ffff881fcda9ba28: ffff883fef727da0 ffffffff81cf63c0 
    ffff881fcda9ba38: 0000000000000000 ffff883fed060000 
    ffff881fcda9ba48: 0000001400000000 ffff000200000003 
    ffff881fcda9ba58: ffff881fcda9bad0 ffff881fcda9bb00 
    ffff881fcda9ba68: ffff883fef152d00 ffffffff81cf6e10 
    ffff881fcda9ba78: 0000000000000000 ffff881fcda9ba90 
    ffff881fcda9ba88: ffffffffc02d10b4 
 #9 [ffff881fcda9ba88] iptable_raw_hook at ffffffffc02d10b4 [iptable_raw]
    ffff881fcda9ba90: ffff881fcda9bac0 ffffffff817280ad 
#10 [ffff881fcda9ba98] nf_iterate at ffffffff817280ad
    ffff881fcda9baa0: ffff883fef152d00 ffff881fcda9bb00 
    ffff881fcda9bab0: ffff883fef152d00 ffff883f208d19a8 
    ffff881fcda9bac0: ffff881fcda9baf0 ffffffff81728126 
#11 [ffff881fcda9bac8] nf_hook_slow at ffffffff81728126
    ffff881fcda9bad0: ffff883fefae0408 ffff883fef152d00 
    ffff881fcda9bae0: ffffffff81cf63c0 ffff883f208d1680 
    ffff881fcda9baf0: ffff881fcda9bb40 ffffffff81733ee4 
#12 [ffff881fcda9baf8] __ip_local_out at ffffffff81733ee4
    ffff881fcda9bb00: 8000000000000003 057fff8000000002 
    ffff881fcda9bb10: 0000000000000000 ffff883fed060000 
    ffff881fcda9bb20: ffff883f208d1680 ffffffff81cf63c0 
    ffff881fcda9bb30: ffffffff81cf6e10 ffffffff817321c0 
    ffff881fcda9bb40: ffff881fcda9bb68 ffffffff81733f0c 
#13 [ffff881fcda9bb48] ip_local_out at ffffffff81733f0c
    ffff881fcda9bb50: ffff883fef152d00 ffff883f208d1680 
    ffff881fcda9bb60: ffffffff81cf63c0 ffff881fcda9bba8 
    ffff881fcda9bb70: ffffffff8173425e 
#14 [ffff881fcda9bb70] ip_queue_xmit at ffffffff8173425e
    ffff881fcda9bb78: ffff883ff1296600 ffff883f208d1680 
    ffff881fcda9bb88: ffff883fef152d00 ffff883f10528510 
    ffff881fcda9bb98: 0000000000000020 0000000000025580 
    ffff881fcda9bba8: ffff881fcda9bc10 ffffffff8174b97b 
#15 [ffff881fcda9bbb0] tcp_transmit_skb at ffffffff8174b97b
    ffff881fcda9bbb8: 00025580ff407480 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bbc8: 0000000000000002 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bbd8: 0631264f0851f19d 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bbe8: ffff883fef152d00 ffff883f208d1680 
    ffff881fcda9bbf8: 0000000000000000 0000000000006d18 
    ffff881fcda9bc08: ffff883f208d1b98 ffff881fcda9bc30 
    ffff881fcda9bc18: ffffffff8174d8bf 
#16 [ffff881fcda9bc18] tcp_send_ack at ffffffff8174d8bf
    ffff881fcda9bc20: ffff883f208d1680 000000000004ab00 
    ffff881fcda9bc30: ffff881fcda9bc50 ffffffff8173bc06 
#17 [ffff881fcda9bc38] tcp_cleanup_rbuf at ffffffff8173bc06
    ffff881fcda9bc40: 0000000000020000 ffff883f208d1680 
    ffff881fcda9bc50: ffff881fcda9bcf0 ffffffff8173d6b6 
#18 [ffff881fcda9bc58] tcp_recvmsg at ffffffff8173d6b6
    ffff881fcda9bc60: ffffffff8137c2b8 ffff881fcad13700 
    ffff881fcda9bc70: ffff881fcad13cd8 ffff881fcad13700 
    ffff881fcda9bc80: 0000000081b66158 ffff883f208d1680 
    ffff881fcda9bc90: ffff881fcda9bec8 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bca0: 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bcb0: 0000000000020000 0000000000020000 
    ffff881fcda9bcc0: 0000000000000000 ffff881fcda9bec8 
    ffff881fcda9bcd0: ffff881fcda9bec8 0000000000020000 
    ffff881fcda9bce0: 0000000000000040 ffff8829577a5780 
    ffff881fcda9bcf0: ffff881fcda9bd10 ffffffff81769aaf 
#19 [ffff881fcda9bcf8] inet_recvmsg at ffffffff81769aaf
    ffff881fcda9bd00: 0000000000000040 ffff8829577a5780 
    ffff881fcda9bd10: ffff881fcda9bd40 ffffffff816d685b 
#20 [ffff881fcda9bd18] sock_recvmsg at ffffffff816d685b
    ffff881fcda9bd20: 00007f950998c8d0 0000000000000040 
    ffff881fcda9bd30: ffff881fcda9bdf8 ffff881fcda9bec8 
    ffff881fcda9bd40: ffff881fcda9beb0 ffffffff816d777b 
#21 [ffff881fcda9bd48] ___sys_recvmsg at ffffffff816d777b
    ffff881fcda9bd50: 00007f950998c8d8 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bd60: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bd70: 00007f94341082c0 0000000000020000 
    ffff881fcda9bd80: 0000000000000001 ffff881eeef31470 
    ffff881fcda9bd90: ffff881eeef30dc0 0000000000000001 
    ffff881fcda9bda0: ffffc9001933ab08 ffff881fcda9bdd0 
    ffff881fcda9bdb0: ffffffff810a74ef 0000000000000001 
    ffff881fcda9bdc0: 00000000ffffffff ffff881fcda9bdf0 
    ffff881fcda9bdd0: ffff881fcda9be40 ffffffff810f8d01 
    ffff881fcda9bde0: ffffc9001933ab04 ffff881fdac5bd40 
    ffff881fcda9bdf0: ffff881eeef31470 ffff881eeef31470 
    ffff881fcda9be00: 00000000021d4000 ffff88140d034380 
    ffff881fcda9be10: 00000000000004a8 00000000021d44a8 
    ffff881fcda9be20: 0000000000000081 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9be30: 00000000021d44a8 0000000000000001 
    ffff881fcda9be40: ffff881fcda9bed8 ffffffff810fb304 
    ffff881fcda9be50: 0000000000000000 ffff883ff1c52c60 
    ffff881fcda9be60: ffff881fcad13700 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9be70: ffff881fcda9be80 00000000e3cd93a0 
    ffff881fcda9be80: ffff881fcda9be90 ffff8829577a5780 
    ffff881fcda9be90: 00007f950998c8d0 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bea0: 00007f950998c8b0 00007f9424068460 
    ffff881fcda9beb0: ffff881fcda9bf38 ffffffff816d8212 
#22 [ffff881fcda9beb8] __sys_recvmsg at ffffffff816d8212
    ffff881fcda9bec0: fffffff700000001 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bed0: 0000000000000000 ffff881f00000000 
    ffff881fcda9bee0: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bef0: ffff881fcda9bd80 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bf00: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bf10: ffff881f00000000 0000000000000000 
    ffff881fcda9bf20: 00007f950998c8d0 00007f950998c8d0 
    ffff881fcda9bf30: 00007f950998e610 ffff881fcda9bf48 
    ffff881fcda9bf40: ffffffff816d8262 
#23 [ffff881fcda9bf40] sys_recvmsg at ffffffff816d8262
    ffff881fcda9bf48: 00007f94340699a8 ffffffff817f6f36 
#24 [ffff881fcda9bf50] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath at ffffffff817f6f36
    RIP: 00007f950b5c88ad  RSP: 00007f950998c890  RFLAGS: 00000293
    RAX: ffffffffffffffda  RBX: 00000000159dfc28  RCX: 00007f950b5c88ad
    RDX: 0000000000000000  RSI: 00007f950998c8d0  RDI: 0000000000000127
    RBP: 00007f94141b0c60   R8: 00007f942c0c91e0   R9: 0000000000000000
    R10: 0000000000020000  R11: 0000000000000293  R12: 00000000fafb8d9d
    R13: 000000000000eac0  R14: 000000003eb48a29  R15: 0000000065fa554f
    ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002f  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

Please let me know if you need further details.